# jQuery update variable referencing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 2 variables set like this:

```
var carousel = $('div.carousel ul');
var pics = carousel.children('li');
```

Later on a few new `<li>` get added to the carousel using `insertBefore()` however my `pics` variable is now out of date so I have to call `pics = carousel.children('li');` again in my function.

Is there a better way of doing this without repeated traversing of the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has an `add()` function which will take an argument and add that to the list of selected items.  You can call `pics.add(newli);` any time you add a new list item to the DOM.

Comment: have to +1 you to get rid of all those 6s. In any case, that's pretty cool to know. Didn't know jquery had something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I like to store jQuery objects to avoid having selectors all over the place. So I created a micro plugin to extend jQuery objects with an `update` function. You can find [the gist here](https://gist.github.com/4340742)

Here is the code for reference:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.update = function(){
    var newElements = $(this.selector),i, oldLength = this.length;
    this.length = newElements.length;
    for(i=0;i<this.length;i++){
      this[i] = newElements[i];
    }
    for(;i<oldLength;i++){
      this[i] = undefined;
    }
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is `pics = carousel.children('li');` so time consuming?

It seem okay to do that again if the list had changed, but if you are really sure you want to avoid it, try adding the 2 new created `li` into a new array and then add pics to it.